# Hard-bricked with dead bootloader Samsung Galaxy Pocket (GT-S5300)

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, clockworkmod-recovery, unbricking, link2sd, samsung-galaxy-pocket

You can see the original files that I used for the partioning from
this website, as well as the other links : https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=F968213B88AADBF5!127&authkey=!AH0DTuPbDvUS7s4

I live in Sri Lanka, and apparently it is not official in my country. The Samsung Service Center does not support my phone, as I bought it from another shop.

I followed all the instructions in the guide. Everything went fine,
and it said that it had finished partitioning 512 MB from my 2GB
Internal USB Storage (My 16GB SD card was inside the phone as well
during the time of partitioning, but it was not partitioned and works
fine when inserted it to my SD card reader/writer). it came back to
the screen that said Re-boot into recovery mode. I pressed the reboot
into recovery mode, and the screen went blank. After that, I could not
boot it normally, and also into recovery or download mode. My phone is
a Samsung Galaxy Pocket (GT-S5300). My phone was rooted with a file (I
do not have that file, and the Dropbox download link was lost), but my
phone worked perfectly after that with no bugs. It ran on Android
Gingerbread (2.3.6) and out of the 960mb of internal space, about
880mb was full.

Note : The old links are no longer there and are dead. The only place
to get the files is from the link mentioned above.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me.

Thanks and best regards,

Sanoo

Answer (score 1):

A carrier or the manufacturer with the correct JTAG setup are likely the only ones who can help you.  If you can't get even the bootloader to work there's nothing you can do as a user.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the agents in my country don't support it, and I don't think the carriers have the correct JTAG. Is there any way to flash the boot-loader using Odin or something without going into download mode?